# Pthread code works fine in linux machine but not on windows using eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, windows, eclipse, pthreads

Demonstrating simple thread.Code runs perfect on linux os, But fails to run on windows.I have added the required library files in eclipse.. The exe crashes at the end. I have tried the same code with linux and it works perfectly fine.I am facing this issue with eclipse using c++ with pthread library added to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

struct thread_data{
   int  thread_id;
   char *message;
};

void *PrintHello(void *threadarg) {
   struct thread_data *my_data;
   try
   {

   my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;

   cout << "Thread ID : " << my_data->thread_id ;
   cout << " Message : " << my_data->message << endl;

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   throw "error in function";
   }
   catch(const char* msg)
   {
       cerr << msg << endl;
   }
}

int main () {
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   struct thread_data td[NUM_THREADS];

   int rc;
   int i;
   try
   {

   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout <<"main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      td[i].thread_id = i;
      td[i].message = "This is message";
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)&td[i]);

      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   throw "error in Main function";

   }
   catch(const char* msg)
   {
       cerr << msg << endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: That do you mean by "fails"? Please provide more details, such as error message or stack trace from crash.

Comment: More details please. What is your error message?

Comment: Do you have pthreads installed on windows? This isn't navtive windows threads.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/ http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/w13-sys/InstallingpthreadsforVisualStudio.pdf

Better option is to use std::thread

Comment: Try `std::thread`, and also clarify your problem

Comment: Yes i have pthreads library installed for windows10 on eclipse cpp. Its gives a run time error with "exe has stopped working" and partial output on the console.

Comment: tried std::thread and i get 'thread' is not a member of 'std' error. I am using GCC 6.3.0 version. Request to give suggestion as to how to proceed.

Comment: I have cross checked on Event Viewer and the exception code is 0xc0000005 which caused the exe to stop working when i use pthreads.

Comment: You have a race condition.  The child threads are referencing the `td` array, which no longer exists after the main thread exits, since it is a local variable.  Either wait for the child threads to exit, or make `td` static.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thankyou for your suggestion,I tried making "td" static, I am still facing the same problem. Can you help as in why the same code works fine in linux but not on windows.

Comment: @PasserBy I tried using std:: thread on visual studio 2017 and it works perfectly fine. But on eclipse cpp it says 'thread' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: Update your eclipse library. And please oh please don't post code in comments

Comment: Sorry about that.I'am actually new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @PasserBy   <thread> in eclipse is inbuilt. How do i update that library.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any guarantee that `cout` will be thread-safe?